# Merge 2D list if duplicate for multiple value

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
[[20, 2, 2, 5], [20, 2, 2, 5], [40, 2, 2, 2, 5]]
```

So, I know dictionary can be used in some of cases. But how will I do it?
**I want to add the first element to the inside list if two element is complete similar**
So the solution will be:

```
[[40,2,2,5],[40,2,2,2,5]]
```

Comment: Please define what is *complete similar*?   Some percentage of numbers?  It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add each row to dictionary (in the key part). The dictionary will remove all the duplicates.
Another way is to add all the rows to a set. And then convert it back to a list . Duplicates will be gone as set removes duplicates.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is kind of vague to me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a empty list, then using if element not in list: list.append(element).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).